# Understanding「七年後で待ってる」

Tags: grammar

This is a title of a newly serialized manga. I have difficulty understanding the title due to the usage of both 後 and ている.

After I read half of the first chapter, I arrived at a conclusion that the title seem to mean

> 七年後**まで**待っている
>
> *I am waiting (for you) **until** seven years have passed*

で and まで is interchangeable in this context. Am I wrong? Also, what is the reading of 後: ご or あと?

Comment: No they are not interchangeable.  7年前、ぼくは記憶を失った……
でも、たった一つ、あの約束だけが忘れられない――

「7年後で待ってる……」
顔も名前も分からない誰かとの約束

失くした記憶のカケラを取り戻すため
そして、あの日交わした約束を果たすため
ぼくはこの街へ帰ってきた――

Comment: @shymander How did you understand で after 七年後 then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 「で」 here is a locative marker, 「七年後」 being a noun referring to the point in time which is 7 years into the future from the time of utterance.

It's the same 「で」 as in「駅で待ってます」('I am/will be waiting at the station.')
where it indicates the location the speaker is/will be waiting.

You would normally use a 「に」 with time expressions in connection with 「待つ」, like 「一時間後にここで待ってます」('I'll be waiting here one hour from now.'), but with the line in question, the speaker uses a 「で」 because they are using the "time-as-space" metaphor. It's something a time-traveler, who has good reason to think of time as space, might aptly say (the term "time-traveler" itself is a specimen of such metaphor) though I'm not sure this person is one.

On the reading of the 「後」. Although I read it as「ご」, and I think more people read it that way than 「あと」, 「あと」 is not incorrect. I can imagine myself hearing people saying it that way and not being surprised or peeved by it at all.

See the 使い分け section on [後／後／先 の解説](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15265/meaning/m0u/) (小学館 類語例解辞典)

> １「後(あと)」は、「事件の三日あと」のように、ある事態が起こった時点を基準とする場合のほか、「あとで電話します」のように、現在を基準にする場合にも用いられる。

and the entry for 「[後(あと)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BE%8C_%28%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%29/#jn-5108)」 on デジタル大辞泉.

> ３ ある時点より前。以前。
> 「四五日―、おれが処へ来て何といった」

That said, I have a sneaking suspicion that the preference and/or (the perception of) correctness for each reading might vary depending on the particle (and which use of it) and verb phrase that comes after it...

Comment: Thanks! How did you read 後 in 七年後?

Comment: @Jimmy Yang Part on the reading added.